# Transform Table Format From Vertical to Horizontal

Tags: excel, pivot

I found a similar post to what I want to achieve but the other way around
https://superuser.com/questions/683413/transform-horizontal-table-layout-to-vertical-table

I want to transform this

| City | Name | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| City A | Company A | Address A |
| City B | Company B | Address B |
| City A | Company C | Address C |
| City B | Company D | Address D |

to this

|  | Name_1 | Address_1 | Name_2 | Address_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| City A | Company A | Address A | Company C | Address C |
| City B | Company B | Address B | Company D | Address D |

I tried using Pivot Table, Power Query, and `measure` and ended up with this result.

|  | Name_1 | Address_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| City A | Company A, Company C | Address A, Address C |
| City B | Company B, Company D | Address B, Address D |

I've been stuck on it for hours but I just can't find a way to do it using Pivot Table. I saw articles about VBA explaining this but I dont have experience with it. Will learn VBA as my last resort.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to the following formula-

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A5),DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(A2:A5),LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,TOROW(FILTER($B$2:$C$5,$A$2:$A$5=x))))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Didn't know this can be done without using Pivot Table.

Answer (score 1):

It's dynamic, if your data has cities with more than 2 names and addresses or 3 plus cities:

```
=LET(
    data, B3:D9,
    city, TAKE(data, , 1),
    ucity, UNIQUE(city),
    nadd, DROP(data, , 1),
    bottom, IFERROR(
        HSTACK(
            SORT(ucity),
            DROP(
                REDUCE(
                    "",
                    SEQUENCE(ROWS(ucity)),
                    LAMBDA(a,v,
                        VSTACK(a, TOROW(FILTER(nadd, INDEX(ucity, v, 1) = city)))
                    )
                ),
                1
            )
        ),
        ""
    ),
    top, HSTACK(
        "City",
        TOROW({"Name","Address"} & EXPAND("", COLUMNS(bottom) / 2, , ""))
    ),
    VSTACK(top, bottom)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

And if you actually wanted to do it within a table, then you couldn't use a spill formula, but you could try setting up a table with the required column headers and a sufficient number of rows, then put this formula in the first column:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(UNIQUE(Table1[City]),ROW()-ROW(Table2[#Headers])),"")
```

and this formula in the remaining columns:

```
=LET(ColOffset,COLUMN()-COLUMN(Table2[[City]:[City]])+1,
  IF(@Table2[[City]:[City]]="","",
    INDEX(FILTER(Table1[[Name]:[Address]],Table1[[City]:[City]]=@Table2[[City]:[City]]),ColOffset/2,MOD(ColOffset,2)+1)))
```

[image]